# MathJax or logical symbolsets?

Tags: feature-request

Could we enable MathJax or a subset of it to support logical explication?

Comment: This would be very helpful. Also, there are quite a few answers on related posts that cite this analysis showing the performance hit incurred by sites that support LaTex: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/10841085, but I doubt the increase in page load times would be an annoyance or even perceptible for most users.

Comment: To be fair to this SE, it would take about as much effort to use the <sup><sub> functions, along with copying-and-pasting of special math/logic symbols, as it would for someone not versed in LaTeX to write out the equivalent in that coding. Other things being equal, granted, it is somewhat more time-consuming to do such things "manually" here, but it can be done. Another method would be to LaTeX some text up in a different place (another SE, or a word processor with the functionality), then screenshot that, crop the shot, and upload the result here.